# How to edit $request-url in middleware in Laravel 5.8 before it hits route API

Tags: url, laravel-5, request, authorization, middleware

I'm developing an API. I want to edit the incoming $request->url so it hits different routes based on the authorization. It should work for any kind of request (POST, GET , DELETE etc...).
By now I 've come this far. The middleware get hit, but **$request->server->set('REQUEST_URI','http://...');**  doesn 't have any effect. The incoming $request url stays at it is. This is the simplified middleware code of the **class RedirectToUrl**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class RedirectToUrl
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
     if($request->user()->role()->first()->role === "admin"){
        $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI','http://rest-api-with-session-httponly:8888/api/admin');
     }elseif($request->user()->role()->first()->role === "basic"){
        $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI','http://rest-api-with-session-httponly:8888/api/basic');
     }else{
        $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI','http://rest-api-with-session-httponly:8888/api/basic');
     }
       
         
        return $next($request);
        
    }
}
```

I`ve put the middleware **RedirectToUrl::class** at the end of the middleware priority:

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AddAuthHeader::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectToUrl::class,
    ];
```

Any hint appreciated.
Thx!

Comment: why would you even attempt to do this ... just redirect them .... the route has already been matched by the time the request is sent through the middleware stack

Comment: Redirecting in Laravel backend, as far as I experienced, is just for GET requests. I`ve tried that. My motivation to try this approach in the first place, was to not send back an unauthorized response to the frontend, and than to send another querrie, but to check the privilges (admin, basic) in the middleware, manipulate the url, so this querrie hit s the route right away. My "fallback"strategy is just sending back an unauthorized with Laravel passport, and than send another request from the frontend, but I try do avoid this "back and forth".

Comment: Thanx, I will go for a redirect!